# Is green Dao supported by kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, greendao

I'm converting my existing java project into the Kotlin , while during this I come across the problem that unresolved ref to 'dao', I tried changing the sequence of greendao & Kotlin dependency as but still facing the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin is 100% [interoperable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/faq.html#is-kotlin-compatible-with-the-java-programming-language) with Java by design, so with some tinkering you can clearly make everything work. If you post your specific problems with the code, the community might be able to help you make the conversion.